# What is the rate limit for Facebook Graph API requests?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app setup in development mode and I am testing against Graph API v2.5. I have a service that will use my app to get the most recent posts, photos, likes and comments from our customers' Facebook business pages at least once an hour. We will probably start off with a few hundred pages, but that may increase to well over 1000 in the near future.

Testing on my machine, I was able to perform 300 requests for the latest post of a page in the span of 5-10 minutes and encountered no errors. Given the scenario I described above, what kind of limits would I run into if I grabbed the data from 1000 pages in the span of an hour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have no problem at all if you use Page Tokens for those Pages. If you try to get data of 1000 Pages, you will definitely have to implement a timeout between the calls. Just because it worked with 300 in a row one time does not mean it works forever, you will definitely get to a limit very soon. So either use a Page Token (highly recommended) or only do a small amount of calls and implement a timeout.

Btw, the official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting